# How to shorten this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the following plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

        if (!opt.a) {
            console.log('a is required!');
            return false;
        }
        if (!opt.b) {
            console.log('b is required!');
            return false;
        }
        if (!opt.c) {
            console.log('c is required!');
            return false;
        }
        //Rest of the logic
    }
    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
    };
});
```

Now this plugin will be called from outside like this:

```
$('div.x').myPlugin({
    a:'aa',
    b:'bb',
    c:'cc'
});
```

As you can see from the plugin I need a, b and c options from outside i.e they are compulsory. But there can 10-15 compulsory options and this code

```
        if (!opt.a) {
            console.log('a is required!');
            return false;
        }
        if (!opt.b) {
            console.log('b is required!');
            return false;
        }
        if (!opt.c) {
            console.log('c is required!');
            return false;
        }
```

can become lengthy and cumbersome. Is there any shorter or smarter way to write this? I was thinking of some common code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are that many, you could put them in an array and check that way:

```
var required = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var index, optname;
for (index = 0; index < required.length; ++index) {
    optname = required[index];
    if (!(optname in opt)) {
        console.log(optname + " is required");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that I've gone for an `if (!(optname in opt))` check there (rather than `if (!opt[optname])` as you originally had), to allow for options that must be specified but for which `0`, `false`, `undefined`, or other falsey values are valid. The `in` check sees whether the option is there without worrying about its value being truthy.

---

Slightly off-topic: You might choose to wait to fail until you've checked for all of the properties, as @Marcus points out in the comments. Also, you might consider throwing an exception rather than returning false, as someone failing to specify the options correctly should be an exceptional condition... But those are minor points.

Comment: @McStretch: Took typing in high school. ;-)

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/t8f3U/) the solution I made which closely resemble T.J's solution. I'd rather not `return false` until after the loop to make sure all missing options are reported. Sadly my answer was removed(?!) before I had the time to add it, but thought I'd share it here.

Comment: @Marcus: Could it be you didn't post your answer in the first place / an error occurred posting it? At my rep level I can see deleted answers (including answers deleted by moderators) and I'm not seeing any from yourself.

Comment: @T.J. Oh. Seems it was a duplicate question, which the creator removed ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I double checked and realised `in` works different in `for` and `if`.

Comment: @Raynos: Got it, I'll delete the above then. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's really confusing when `in` is context sensitive :(

Comment: @Raynos: :-) Far from the only thing that varies its meaning based on what it's part of. `:` comes to mind. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(['a','b','c'], function(key, val) {
    if (!opt[val] !== void 0) console.log(val + " is require");
});
```

An `$.each` is just so much shorter/tidier.

It's the same thing as @T.J.Crowder's answer though.

P.S. `void 0 === undefined`

Comment: You'd have to have a flag saying to return false after the `each` loop (or throw an exception).

Comment: Re `void 0`: Worried about `undefined` getting redefined? Or just saving characters? (It doesn't help you with the cross-window `undefined` problem that's the usual reason for using `typeof` instead.) Also, just being picky, but this isn't *quite* the same as mine as this doesn't allow an option to be specified with the value `undefined`. But that's a nit (and neither did the OP's version). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `void 0` returns the real `undefined`. I also think options specified as `undefined` should be treated the same as them not being there. `foo["foo"] = undefined` and `delete foo["foo"]` are treated the same in my books. This is what `null` is for if you don't want a value in that option. `undefined` is not something you should be manually passing around, but that's an opinionated manner. Thanks for pointing out the `return false` thing, that would become a pain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as for the `return false` thing we should use `Array.prototype.every` ;). IE8 must die so we can use ES5.

Comment: @Raynos: Re ECMAScript5: Hey, I'm still waiting for **IE6** to die. ;-)

Comment: @Raynos: *"`void 0` returns the real `undefined`"* So does `undefined` unless someone's done something silly and shadowed it.

Comment: @Raynos: (Sorry for the mulitple posts) *"foo["foo"] = undefined and delete foo["foo"] are treated the same in my books"* Then you need better books. There's a *big* difference between a property not existing, and a property existing with the value `undefined.`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there are clear differences between the two, but your code becomes a mess of edge cases if your API starts treating them as separate cases. I simply thinking its bad design to treat the two as two different things. Also `window.undefined = true; void 0 == true; // false`

Comment: @Raynos: Treating them differently is absolutely the right thing in some situations (and absolutely not in others); it totally depends on the use-case. Regarding `undefined`: Again, that's doing something silly and shadowing it. Don't do that. :-) Just like you don't do `window.RegExp = String;` or `window.document = {}`, both of which you can also do, but neither of which you *should* do or worry about someone doing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know you should never have to worry about `undefined` being not `undefined` ;) Just pre emptive defence againts a witty `undefined = true;` comment :).